# Rails URI(request.referer).path regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, request

I would like to know from cart controller from which URL I come: If I come from '/' or '/search' the parameter is a Serie Model, if I come from /'1-9+' it's a Season Model and finally /'1-9+/1-9+' is a Chapter Model.

I've seen that `URI(request.referer).path` shows the path, but I don't know how to make that regexp.

There is any simple way of knowing from what view it comes? I have problems storing them because they are different Models, and the parameter is the primary_key so I don't know on which model I have to search that key.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to differentiate these requests would be to not use regexp but to declare appropriate routes in your routes.rb file

> get '/' => 'series#index'
>
> get '/search' => 'series#search'
>
> get '/:season' => 'seasons#show'
>
> get '/:season/:chapter' => 'chapters#show'

In the last route, params[:season] and params[:chapter] will be set based on your URL

Comment: This will require the user to define separate actions for each route. If the way user want to handle the request is completely different for each case, this solution will makes sense. However if the user wants to only use 'Season','Chapter' etc as just one of the variables in the controller logic, then this solution will lead to code duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If from within the controller action you want to know which route the request came from, better to let rails routing handle the regex part for you and you can simply add identifiers as extra parameter from the routes.rb itself.

```
get '/' => 'your_controller#your_action', :type => "Series"
get '/search' => 'your_controller#your_action', :type => "Series"
get '/:season' => 'your_controller#your_action', :type => "Season"
get '/:season/:chapter' => 'your_controller#your_action', :type => "Chapter"
```

the identifier will be available in your controller action as params[:type] in this case

Also as a good practice, never begin your routes with variables. Always namespace them. Otherwise they will start getting matched with any other routes.
for e.g. use `get 'some_namespace/:season'` instead of `get '/:season'`

Comment: The problem is that /, /search, /:season, /:season/:chapter redirect to '/addproduct' for adding product, and :type is not available there.

Comment: Added an edit for how you should actually define routes, Even if you do want to use routes like GET '/:variable' , put it at bottom of your routes.rb file as the routes are matched top to bottom.

Comment: :type is just an example of variable name you can use. You can give it any other variable name you want.